# Push notification for android and ios in laravel with queue

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, laravel-5.3, laravel-queue

I am using `davibennun/laravel-push-notification` package for sending notification to device. But I want to send notification to multiple users for that i want to use `laravel queue`. But i am new to `laravel` that's why don't know how to use queue with notification.

I have created the migrate the queue table and have created the job by 
`php artisan make:job SendPushNotification` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running following command

`php artisan make:job SendPushNotification`

From your controller

`$user = User::all();
 $other_data = array('message' => 'This is message');
 SendPushNotification::dispatch($user, $other_data);`

In app\Jobs\SendPushNotification.php

```
protected $contacts;
protected $sms_data;

public function __construct($users, $other_data)
{
    //

  $this->users = $users;
  $this->other_data = $other_data;
}


public function handle()
{

    $users = $this->users;
    $other_data = $this->other_data;


    foreach($users as $key => $value){

      // You code
   }
```

Run following command

`php artisan queue:work`

Comment: This really helped me, thank you very much. I created a SendPushNotification class with parameters user_id, message, title